# What is the radiation density in a spherical oven? Does this pertain to the universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, photons, thermal-radiation

Imagine a spherical oven with radius R. The inside of the spherical wall is at temperature T (everywhere) and is assumed emit perfect black body radiation (everywhere).

(1) What is the energy density in the interior of the oven?

(2) Is the energy density homogeneous or does it depend on the radius?

Klaus-Frank

I wonder whether the radiation density of the universe can be described in this way, i.e., as result of a "hot" horizon. Of course, in this case there is the additional issue that the horizon ("oven wall") is growing with time.

Comment: Homework-*type* questions are generally off-topic without reasonable effort being made by the OP.  It does not have to be homework as-in-school, it can be also cover self-study and curiosity type questions.

Comment: I was wondering wether the radiation density of the universe can be understood as result of the temperature of the horizon. I added the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's uniform, of course. If it weren't uniform, you could quickly seal off two portions with different radiation densities, and use the difference to extract work. Extracting work from a bath of uniform temperature violates the second law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to (1) is that the energy density is $4\sigma T^4/c$, where $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the absolute temperature, and $c$ is the speed of light. A derivation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). Note that the oven radius $R$ is irrelevant as far as the energy *density* is concerned.

The Stefan-Boltzmann constant can be expressed in terms of more fundamental physical constants as

$$\sigma=\frac{2\pi^5k^4}{15c^2h^3},$$

where $k$ is Boltzmann’s constant and $h$ is Planck’s constant.